# Unexpected error in android app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullpointerexception

I made a small app in android studio, which is `tic tac (XO)` game. All was working fine and I've tested the app on the *emulator* many times. But at a moment the application crashed and the well known message says: **Unfortunately, "tictactoe has stopped"**. And then I wasn't even able to start the app, all the time it crashes when trying to run it.

**Android *logcat* showed those messages:**

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>      E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {.tictactoe/.tictactoe.MainGame}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>  
>    E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2575)
>     
>  E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2603)
>      E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2089)
>      E/AndroidRuntime:   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)

With many more messages. Any help?

Update: more logcat:

> E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
>      E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>      E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

Comment: please post your complete Logcat and the relevant code too..

Comment: from your logcat that is posted, i can understand that the Null pointer exception is raised in your `onResume()`.

Comment: @Lal I tryed to post the complete logcat, put the stackoverflow wditor refused it!

Comment: try editing the question once more..

Comment: my problem is that the app worked fine, and then crashed without even editing my code!

Comment: do you have onReume() in your code?

Comment: I edited the question, it refused much of the text

Comment: add your logcat in comments

Comment: @Lal No I have no code in onResume

Comment: please show you code..

Comment: sorry onResume have some code:
 protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        IsBackGround = false;
        mPlayer.start();
    }

Comment: may be `IsBackGround ` or `mPlayer` is null..show your code please..

Comment: @Lal and Knossos and every one, I solved the problem, the issue was with null pointer to Media player, some code may be deleted by mistake or so, and that lead to NULL pointer exception. Thank you for help!

Comment: It's always good to catch the exceptions and print the stack traces to debug more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `saveBundleState` and `onResumeBundleState` to hold important view items information. You likely have elements in the main activity OnCreate which use generated views/items right?

You also need to make sure this is present:

```
onPause(){
super.onPause;
//DO SOME CODE TO SAVE BUNDLE
}

onResume(){
super.onResume;
//DO SOME CODE TO REOPEN BUNDLE
}
```